# JS Is it possible to access function variable?

Tags: javascript, function

My understanding is that with JavaScript a "function", is a function, but can also be a constructor, and an object itself. If I design a function like a function (with a return), but also like a constructor, can I ever have access to both the return value, and that property outside of the function scope? Like so

```
function Tree() {
    this.name = "Boris";
    var age = 18
    var cookies = "cookies"    // defined with var instead of this.cookies

    return age;
}

var r1 = Tree();       // r1 == 18
r1.name                // undefined
var r2 = new Tree();   // r2 == { name: "Boris" }, but no age or cookies
```

So can I ever access name, age, and cookies with the same object? The more and more I think this over, what I want to do probably isn't possible because of security reasons, but I still would like to know.

Using `obj.constructor()` you once again have access to the function you used to create the obj, and thus the return value. Note: prefixing with `new` will return another object, not the return value.

```
 var r2 = new Tree();   // r2 == { name: "Boris" }
 r2.constructor()       // 18
 new r2.constructor()   // { name: "Boris" }, not what I want
```

I couldn't find a way to access variables defined with var. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So can I ever access name, age, and cookies with the same object?

**No**, and this "non-accessibility" contributes to make *sort of* private variables and encapsulation possible in javascript.

---

#### Example which allow access to everything:

```
function Tree() {
    if (!this) return new Tree();
    this.name = "Boris";
    var age = 18
    var cookies = "cookies"    // defined with var instead of this.cookies
    this.getAge = function() { return age; };
    this.getCookies = function() { return cookies; };
}
```

Comment: While it solves the problem, the trouble with this is the functions are defined on every Tree instance, rather than once on Tree.prototype (as I'm sure you're aware, but I thought I'd make explicit)

Comment: @jackweirdy How would it look to define these methods on the prototype if they are private though?

Comment: The functions are defined on every Tree instance because the example does encapsulation with closure. If you don't want to bother, better do ```this.age = 18``` and ```this.cookies = "cookies"```

Comment: @Volune how do you mean _"sort of private"_?

Comment: "_sort of private variables and encapsulation_", because there is no private variable and encapsulation like other languages can provide.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get variable from function. The reason for it - [function scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), take a look.

But if you still want to get variables, I propose make your code in this way:

```
function Tree() {
    this.name = "Boris";
    this.age = 18;
    return this;
}
```

So you need use `this` if you want get access to variables.

OR

You can define properties in prototype. For example:

```
function Tree() {
    this.name = 'Boris';
    return this;
}

Tree.prototype = Object.create({
    age: 18
});

var tree = new Tree();
tree.name == 'Boris'; // true
tree.age == 18; // true
```

But you can't get access to variables defined with `var` if this variable closed in function scope.

Comment: Why do you use Tree.prototype to set the age?

Comment: @jackweirdy you can set default values in many ways. And setting value to prototype it can be technique that helps set default values for object. If ```tree``` instance will have ```this.age = 30``` then ```tree.age == 30```. But if ```this.age``` not defined then ```tree.age == 18```. It's just one from many variants to make that.

Comment: Also you can do this by ```this.age = age || 18``` in your constructor, of course. You decide what to use :)

Answer (score 0):

A function is considered to be a constructor when called with the `new` keyword. For example:

```
function Cat(name) {
  this.name = name;
  return "my name is " + this.name;
}

var a = new Cat("barry");
var b = Cat("larry");
```

Here, `a` is assigned to the result of using the `Cat` function as a constructor, whereas `b` is the result of calling `Cat` as a plain function. `typeof b` would be `"string"` as the result is simply the return value of the function.

`typeof a` would be `"object"`, as the new keyword changes the expression behaviour - it makes a new object, and calls the constructor function in such a way (known as *binding*) that the `this` variable is a reference to that object. the result of that expression is the `this` object, *not* the return value, as you noted.

What you seem to be describing is wanting private variables - that is, variables which are accessible within object functions (eg `a.addOneToAge()`), but not from direct reference via `a.age` or something similar. While generally possible in JavaScript using closures, this isn't possible (that I'm aware) on objects.

Comment: That's useful what you explained about _binding_. How do you mean private variables are possible via closures but not objects. Wouldn't the implementation by @Volune create the getter method for the var on the object?

Comment: That's exactly what volune's doing - because the function is inside the constructor (perhaps *enclosed* is a better word here), the function has access to the variable. Trouble is, that function is constructed and copied on *every* instance. That performance hit is probably negligible, the JavaScripty thing to do would be to define the function once on the prototype - but then you can't seal the variable away.